# Authenticate private registry (ACR) with Minikube on developer machine

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, minikube, acr

At my company, we're setting up an on-prem k8s cluster in combination with a private image repository hosted on Azure (Azure Container Registry).

For development purposes, I'd like our developers to be able to run the apps they create locally using minikube. ACR offers several ways to authenticate, including:

- Indiviual login
- Access Token
- Service Principal

When developing locally, and using the Docker CLI, individual authentication can be setup by running `az acr login -n my-repository.azurecr.io`. We manage all SSO authentication through Azure Active Directory, and Docker Desktop comes with the `docker-credentials-wincred.exe` extension, to delegate handling of authentication to the Windows Credential Store. This is specified in `~\.docker\config.json`. Pretty neat and seamless, love it.

However, when authenticating k8s to work with a ACR, most documentation steers you towards setting up a Service Principal, and storing credentials in a k8s secret. For a production environment this makes perfect sense, but for a developer machine it feels a bit weird to authenticate using headless credentials.

An alternative is to pull images manually, and set `imagePullPolicy` to `IfNotPresent` in the k8s manifest. The tricky part here is that Minikube runs in a separate VM, with its own Docker daemon. By default, Docker CLI is not configured to connect with this daemon. Minikube exposes some control over the daemon through the minikube CLI (e.g. `minikube image pull`) but here we run into authorization issues. Alternatively, we can configure the Docker CLI - which is already configured to use the Windows credentials store - to connect to the minikube daemon. This is pretty straight-forward using `minikube docker-env`.

So, this works... but my question is: isn't there a more sensible way to do this? Can't `minikube image` somehow be configured to work with the windows credentials store?

Comment: I think that should somehow work,start Minikube with API Server Flags.

Comment: Thanks @RichardRublev, what do you mean by start minikube with API server flags?

Comment: Read https://aro-labs.com/kubernetes-aad-auth.html,I do not have time now to look at my past projects.